# How to avoid the creation of automatic links?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, automatic-edits

I'm trying to answer a question, and for that I need to mark 4 different mock (fake) urls and what they'd have. When I type this, a link is automatically created, and I would like to avoid this behaviour since this page doesn't exist. I want to create a link only if I do [] () without space in the middle. Is this even possible? Example of what I mean:

http://www.example.com/index.php

```
Code for that page
```

That shouldn't have a link automatically created since it doesn't exist, but inserting it in code is not feasible (because next line is code for that page and there should be a separation). Block quotes didn't work either. I'm asking if this is possible without breaking the url itself, only the hyperlink.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can put the URL inside backticks, like this:

```
`http://www.example.com/index.php`
```

This results in a valid URL without a generated hyperlink:

`http://www.example.com/index.php`

```
Code for that page
```

Comment: True, you can also have it all in code block and separate the lines using HTML comment, see the source of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127080/152859) for an example.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That page is just awesome.

Comment: Cheers @Frank feel free to use it for your own tests. :)

Answer (score 7):

From this excellent [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175726/171231) to a very similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175725/171231):

You can put the URL escape a / with a \, like this:

```
http:\//www.example.com/index.php
```

This results in a valid URL without a generated hyperlink:

http://www.example.com/index.php

```
Code for that page
```

Note that the live preview will show the \, but the actual rendering won't.